# Aparicion de aplicacion con simbolo menos (-) panel-collapse collapse

Tags: php, html, html5

Tengo la siguiente pagina que esta desarrollada en Php y Html:

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren muy bien, quiero pedirles el favor con lo siguiente, tengo Tengo la siguiente pagina que esta desarrollada en Php y Html (El enlace es el siguiente: https://dev.ziursoftware.com/capacitacion_software_contable2.php), necesito que dicha pagina al abrirse me muestre la información desplegada tal como esta, pero con la diferencia es que necesito que no solo el primer simbolo aparezca con (-), sino tambien todos los demas  y el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
//MIGRADO A mysqli el 20/12/2018 por LERN
global $pagActual, $meta_Descripcion, $meta_Keywords, $title, $scripts, $styles;
$pagActual="06";
$meta_Descripcion = "Esta el cronograma de capacitaciones que se realizan por internet en Ziur software";
$meta_Keywords = "capacitación software contable, capacitación ziur, software contable";
$title = "Capacitaciones Virtuales - Ziur Software";
include("Conexion.php");
$link=Conectarse();
$opcion = -1; //coment 17 Junio 2022 10:58 a.m $opcion = -1;
$opcion = isset($_POST["IdTipoCurso"]) ? $_POST["IdTipoCurso"] : "0";
//Llenar el combo de modalidades de tipos cursos
//--
$strSql = "select IdTipo, NomTipo from Cursos_Tipos where IdTipo IN(0,2)";
$result= $link->query($strSql);
$comboTiposCursos = "<select name='IdTipoCurso' onchange='javascript:this.form.submit();'><option value=''>--</option>";
while($items=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$sel ="";
if ($items["IdTipo"]==$opcion)
$sel="selected";
$comboTiposCursos = $comboTiposCursos . "<option " . $sel . " value=\"".htmlspecialchars($items['IdTipo'])."\">".$items['NomTipo']." </option>";
}
$comboTiposCursos = $comboTiposCursos . "</select>";
//--
$numdia = date("N");
if ($numdia > 0)
$numdia = date("d") - ($numdia-1);
$fechaini = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("n"),$numdia,date("Y")));
$numdia += 6;
$fechafin = date("Y-m-d",mktime(23,59,59,date("n"),$numdia,date("Y")));
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","S&aacute;bado");
$meses = array("","Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
$where ="";
$orderby = " order by Cur_Prog.Fecha asc ";
switch ($opcion)
{
case -1:
$where = "";
break;
case 0:
$where = " and Cur_Prog.Tipo = 0 ";
$orderby = " order by Cur_Prog.Fecha asc ";
break;
case 2:
$where = " and Cur_Prog.Tipo = 2 ";
$orderby = " order by Cur_Prog.Fecha asc ";
break;
}
$strSql = "SELECT Cur.CodCurso, Cur.NomCurso, Cur.DescripCurso, Cur.Duracion, Cur_Prog.Fecha, Cur_Prog.HoraIni, Cur_Prog.HoraFin, Cur_Prog.UrlVideo, Cur_Prog.DescripCurso as DescripCurso2, Cur_Prog.Tipo, Cur_Prog.UrlConferencia " .
"FROM Cursos_Disponibles AS Cur INNER JOIN Cursos_Programacion AS Cur_Prog ON Cur.IdCurso = Cur_Prog.IdCurso " .
"WHERE Cur_Prog.EsActivo = 1 and Cur_Prog.Fecha >= CURDATE()" . $where . $orderby ;
$result = $link->query($strSql);
$senFirst = true;
////$senFirst = false;
$strIn ="";
$i=0;
?>
<?php
include("_parteEncab_New2019.php");
?>
<!-- offer section start -->
<section class="offer-area bg-color-7 offer-two section-padding">
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-text-center">
<div class="section-title">
<h2>Capacitaciones</h2>
<div class="title-line">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="accordion-one">
<ul id="accordion" class="panel-group clearfix">
<?php
while($row =$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$i++;
// $strClassResp ="paypal-dsc panel-collapse collapse";   coment 21 de junio 2022
 $strClassResp ="panel-collapse collapse in"; //puesto 21 de junio 2022

if ($senFirst)
{
     
    $strClassResp ="panel-collapse collapse in"; //puesto 21 de junio 2022
 

$senFirst = true;
}
$time = strtotime($row["Fecha"]);
switch ($row["Tipo"])
{
case "0":
$strTipo = "VIRTUAL";
break;
case "1":
$strTipo = "INTERNO";
break;
case "2":
$strTipo = "PRESENCIAL";
break;
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="7">
<li class="panel">
<div class="capacitacioncontenedor">
<div class="fecha">
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $i ?>"> <!--Si quito el <?php //echo $i ?> me mostrara todo en + y quedara disfuncional el incrementador o decrementador  -->
<div class="faq-heading">  <!--faq-heading es +,faq-p es - -->
  
<h3><?php echo $row["NomCurso"] ?></h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="<?php echo $strClassResp ?>" id="collapse<?php echo $i ?>">   <!-- 21 de junio 2022 OJO CENTRO INCONVEIENTE -->
<div class="faq-p"> 
<div class="row">
<div class="all-service clearfix">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="single-service margin-bottom">
 <div class="service-icon-one">   
</div>
<div class="service-text">
<span style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">
<? echo $dias[date("N",$time)] ?>
<br />
</span>
<span style="font-size: 14px;">
<? echo date("d", strtotime($row["Fecha"])) . " " . $meses[date("n",$time)] . " " . date("Y", strtotime($row["Fecha"]))?>
</span> <!--Viene de la base de datos -->
<br />
Horario
<br />
<span style="font-size: 14px; ">
<?php echo date("h:i", strtotime($row["HoraIni"])) . " - " . date("h:i", strtotime($row["HoraFin"])) ?>
</span>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>     
</div>     

<!------------------ >
<!-- <div class="all-service clearfix"> -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="single-service margin-bottom">
<div class="service-text">
<span style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">
<!--17 de junio 2022, Aqui debe de venir lo de Configuración de sistema -->
<?php echo $row["NomCurso"] ?> <!--Viene de la base de datos -->
<br />
</span>
<!-- <p></p> -->
<span style="font-size: 14px;">
<?php echo $row["DescripCurso"] ?> <!--Viene de la base de datos -->
</span>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-------------------->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="single-service margin-bottom">
<div class="service-text">
<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
Código
<br />
</span>
<span style="font-size: 14px;">
<? echo $row["CodCurso"] ?> 
</span>
<br />
<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
Tipo:
<br />
</span>
<span class="pandin-1" >
<?php echo $strTipo ?>
</span>
<p></p>
<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
Duración:
<br />
</span>
<span class="pandin-1" >
<?php echo $row["Duracion"] ?> Horas
</span>
<br />
</div>
<!-- 17 de junio 2022 </div>  -->
<br />
<div class="contenidocapacitacion">

 <a href="<?php echo $row["UrlConferencia"] ?>"  target="_blank" style="background-color:DodgerBlue;">
    <button style="background-color:#2E9AFE;">Realizar Registro</button>
  </a> 

 
<!-- </div> -->
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</table>
</div>
<!-- 17 de junio 2022 10: 27 am</div>   -->
</section>
<!-- offer section end -->
<?php
include("_parteFin_New2019.php");
?>
<?php
//Liberar recursos
//--
$result->closeCursor();
$link=null;
//--
?>
```

E comparado los dos textos del codigo, es decir la parte que esta con + y con - y pese a que hay diferencias al momento de trasladar el segmento de código de lo que se encuentra con - en todo el código me aparece con error.

Gracias por la ayuda

php html.

Comment: Que se supone que hace el codigo? con dejarnos un archivo completo no es de gran ayuda, deberias ser preciso con tu pregunta, porque veo alli mucho codigo y el que trate de ayudar no va a estar 1 hora simplemente viendo que hace

Comment: Como te comente anteriormente, debes plasmarlo bien en tu pregunta con las debidas etiqutas para que la pregunta pueda ser entendida

Comment: @ernesto jimenez es que desafortunadamente no me deja incluir etiquetas al código